# Proving infinite subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove:

An infinite subset of a denumerable set is denumerable.

I understand this has been asked before and I did take the time to read what was said there, but I do not understand still.

I have to prove this using other theorems about denumerable or countable sets, nothing too complex for this proof.

Comment: There is some ambiguity in what you mean by countable. See the first few paragraphs at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set

Comment: @parsiad For me a set is countable if it is finite or denumerable.

Comment: So you know that subsets of countable sets are countable?

Comment: @LeBtz yes I did mention that. We did learn that theorem.

Comment: Then I don't understand the difficulty. An infinite subset of a denumerable set is an infinite subset of a countable set and therefore countable itself. Now it can't be finite because it's infinite by assumption so it must be denumerable.

Comment: @LeBtz     How are you getting that an infinite subset of a denumerable set is an infinite subset of a countable? Isn't countable and denumerable different?

Comment: As far as I  know, denumerable set and countable set are synonyms.

Comment: @user254665 are they really? I thought there was a difference? Now I am confused...

Comment: Your own definition of countable says that each denumerable set is countable by definition.

Comment: @LeBtz I just understood what you said, it just clicked. I get it now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the subset is not a countable infinite set, so if you prove that your subset $A$ must be more than countable in order to be infinite you have done, because then it can't be a subset of you denumerble set. Suppose that there exists an infinite set $B$ whose cardinality is less than the cardinality of the natural numbers that is infinite; so there exists an injective function $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb N$: its image is infinite by hypothesis, and it is a subset of the natural numbers so it has a minimum $x_0$: associate this minimum with $0$ and then consider the set $f(B)\setminus x_0$ and iterate considerating the new minimum $x_1$; your process never ends because $f(B)$ is infinite. So we have shown that there is a bijection between $B$ and $\mathbb N$, that is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Are countable and denumerable somewhat separate?

Comment: In my answer I have used them as synonyms: however, the meaning depends on the author, for example someone uses countable only for infinite sets.

Comment: For me countable means finite or denumerable. Denumerable is a set equivalent to the natural numbers.

Comment: Ok, however the proof is the same even using "your" definition.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many possible proofs:

If a set $A$ is denumerable, then there is a bijection $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb N$

So if $B\subseteq A$,the restriction of $f$ to $B$, which is $f:B\rightarrow \mathbb  N$ is $1:1$

On the other side, if $B$ is infinite, we can construct an $1:1$ function $g:\mathbb N\rightarrow B$ by defining $f(0)=x_0\in B$, then $f(1)=x_1\in B-\{x_0\}$, and so on by induction.

So by [Schröder–Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) there is a bijection between $B$ and $\mathbb N$, which makes $B$ denumerable.

Comment: Just as a disclaimer, I have not learned the Bernstein Theorem